# ObjectMapper | dynamic mapping

Tags: java, spring, generics, objectmapper

I'm facing a problem on my project: I have 3 classes (B,C,D) which all extend another class (A) and I want to have a single method that maps a String to one of these 3 classes.

I came up with the following solution:

```java
public MySuperclass mapDynamicallyToObject(String stringObject, Object theClass) {
    return new ObjectMapper()
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true)
        .readerFor(theClass.getClass())
        .readValue(stringObject);
}
```

But it doesn't work at runtime.

By reading Oracle's docs, I thought that by using the Object's method **.getClass()** the JVM would have been able to determine at runtime  the true nature of the object and map the string to it.

Where I am mistaken? Did you face a similar issue? How did you approach it?

By the way, I'm just learning about Generics and I would have liked to use it here rather than using "Object theClass", but it didn't recognize the letter **T** as a generic.

P.s. if it can be of any help, I am using Spring Boot.

Thank you all in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you show how you call this method? I'd rather expect something like `<T> T parse(String input, Class<T> klass) { return objectMapper.readValue(input, klass); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Has been a while, but here is the solution:

```
public Object mapDynamicallyToObject(String stringObject, Class clazz) {
    return new ObjectMapper()
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true)
        .readerFor(clazz)
        .readValue(stringObject);
}
```

And when the method is invoked it requires casting

```
MyClass myClass = (Myclass) this.mapDynamicallyToObject(theString, MyClass.class);
```